# How power and exponential are related?

Tags: exponential-function

I have a model to fit but I am not sure if it is correct:

> Is $\exp(ax+bz+c)^d$ algebraically the same as $\exp(dax+dbz+dc)$?

## Edit

what about this one?

> Is $[exp(ax+bz+c)+j]^d$ algebraically the same as as $[exp(dax+dbz+dc)+dj]$

Where `a,b,c,j,d` are parameters for non-linear regression fit.

If so, why? Can you explain please?

Comment: It would help to have more parentheses there: both $(\exp(x))^d$ and $\exp(x^d)$ are unambiguous, while $\exp(x)^d$ is something that will make the reader wonder about the intended meaning.

Comment: @Woodface Thanks my question is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.  Note that $\exp(z) = e^z$, where $e$ is a number given by $e = 2.71828...$.  It then follows from a basic property of exponents that
$$
\exp(ax + bz + c)^d = \\
\left[e^{ax+bz+c}\right]^d =\\
e^{(ax+bz+c)d} =\\
e^{dax + dbz + dc} =\\
\exp(dax + dbz + dc)
$$

Comment: Thanks.I edited my question would you please have a look.

Comment: The answer to that one is no, for the same reason.